# Linux x64 syscall for directory listing

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

How can i get a directory file listing in Linux from a Linux x64 shellcode ?

I was thinking i just have to open folder as a file with open and read syscalls but it does not work...

Thanks

Comment: Check out the `getdents` system call.  Read the manual for how it works.

Comment: "it does not work" isn't a great description. What happens? Errors? Unexpected behaviour? Something else? Also, it would be better if we could *see* the code that "does not work" rather than having to imagine it for ourselves.

Comment: As a followup to fuz's comment, you can find a shellcode example related to your question for 64-bit Linux here: https://github.com/t00sh/assembly/blob/master/shellcodes/linux/x86-64/ls_syscall.asm .Mor einfo here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html

Comment: That's correct, `sys_read` doesn't work on directory.  Use `strace ls` to see what system calls it uses.